# An inheritance is divided between three people in the ratio 4:7:2. If the least amount received is $2300 calculate...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An inheritance is divided between three people in the ratio $4:7:2$. If the least amount received is $\$\ 2300$ calculate how much the other two people received?

Comment: The amounts will be $4x,7x,2x$ for some positive real $x$. The least is $2x$, so $2x=2300\implies x=1150$. Calculate the other two using this value.

Comment: I swear I did it yesterday but my dog ate my homework! :-P seriously, we are not here to solve homework.. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @RossMillikan, thanks! Fixed it. :)

Comment: @Ant I solved it, laaaa :P

Answer (score 2):

If the amount is distributed in the ratio $4:7:2$ then you know the person who got the least got:$$\frac{2}{4+7+2}=\frac{2}{13}$$of the total amount.

Use this fact to arrive at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

we have 13 parts in the total amount: 4 + 7 + 2 = 13 parts
The lowest person receives 2 parts that is 2300 and so 2300/2= 1150 for each part. Thus the total amount is (1150 * 13) = 14950

Therefore:

> 2/13 * 14950 = 2300
>
> 4/13 * 14950 = 4600
>
> 7/13 * 14950 = 8050
>
> 2300 + 4600 + 8050 = 14950

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$$4:7:2 = x:y:2300=x:y:(2\times1150)=\dots$$

so now you multiply 1150 with 4 and  7.